# Long text not splitting into multiline using AutoCompleteTextView in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my `android` app and it is displaying area names in the dropdown which are coming from the server. Some of the area names are quite long so I want to display such names into `multi-lines`. I have created a separate `xml` file for the `textview` of the dropdown and set `singleLine` property to `false` and `ellipsize` to `none` but it's not working.

This is my `AutoCompleteTextView`

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:hint="@string/customer">

                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/customerField"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:inputType="text"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

This is my `dropdown_item_multiline`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" />
```

And this is how I am setting the adapter to `AutoCompletTextView`

```
ArrayAdapter customersAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                        R.layout.dropdown_item_multiline,
                        Utils.getCustomersNames(filteredCustomersMap));
                customerDropdown.setAdapter(customersAdapter);
```

Comment: maybe, the issue is generated just because you give a fix height of `TextInputLayout` and `AutoCompleteTextView` give a wrap_content to it.

Comment: @MohakShah no that's not a problem. I tried giving same height but still same issue.